# Dramatically increase the memory when adding transparent view as a subview

Tags: ios, memory-management

My View hierarchy,

> UIScrollView
>         UIImageView
>           OverlayView

OverlayView is a transparent view and purpose of that view is freehand drawing.

I have taken OverlayView is of same size as UIImageView.

Let me explain it with the example and some data what I am getting,

UIScrollView is at zoom scale: 5 and `UIImageView is of Size: 4000*3000` (i.e. Actually UIImageview is in zoomed state.) At this level memory consumption is 50Mb.

Whenever I am adding this OverlayView, memory increase by 200Mb. Not sure why memory increased dramatically.

And when I am starting to move my finger on overlay view for freehand drawing, in a 3 or 5  seconds memory consumption is reached to around `630Mb`.

**Is this the issue because of the big size of UIView?**

```
What is the easiest solution to fix this issue?
```

If this problem is just because of the size then one solution can be I can take to view of size of only visible are not the size of UIImageView but I am not preferring this because I need to do lots of conversion of Points to get the desired points.

**`Update:`**

If I am changing the view hierarchy to below(Overlay view is a subview of UIImageView rather than scrollview) then consumes lots of less memory then above mentioned hierarchy. even I can say memory issue completely resolved.

> UIScrollView
>         UIImageView
>                OverlayView

```
Still curious to know why this is happening?
```

Comment: If you are using simulator, please test it on real device and than check memory consumption. Simulator memory consumption behaves different that on device.

Comment: Where are you checking this memory usage? Instruments or Xcode (In Xcode 5 there Memory usage shown under Debug Navigator). 

If Xcode then it will not show the memory usage properly. Check with Instruments.

Comment: I am testing in Device. And Using the "Allocation" tool

Comment: The size of the view shouldn't be a problem here, it's more than likely something going on in code. When you say the 'purpose of that view is freehand drawing' do you mean you're actually rendering the overlay view out to an image at some point? Perhaps if you post some of your code you might get more helpful answers

Comment: @lxt: See I have updated the question with my observation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This memory issue is just because of the size of `UIView`.

I got one link from the stack overflow : [Drawing a grid in UIScrollView's subview allocates huge memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21446237/drawing-a-grid-in-uiscrollviews-subview-allocates-huge-memory)

That answer is clearing saying if any view override DrawRect method will consume memory :

```
bound.size.width * bound.size.height*contentScale*contentScale*4
```

As I stated in question before adding the overlay memory consumption was 50Mb. And after adding the overlay it becomes approx.200Mb.

Size of overlay was: 4000*3000
So, memory consumed by overlay will be:(4000*3000*2*2*4) (i.e. This calculation is as per above formula.) In Mb it becomes around 183Mb

Now adding this view into imageview fix this problem because that image view is the view that is being zoomed by scrollview. So, obviously at any number of zoom scale size of overlay view will be fix but it will be scaled as per zoom scale.